# What's happened to my save game?

Tags: windows, assassins-creed-2

I started Assasssin's Creed 2 this morning, and I found a very bad surprise. All of the missions played the day before haven't been saved. All of sequence 3, from **Casa Dolce Casa** to **A Change of Plans**, has been lost.

Any clue as to why and how that happened and how I can avoid this situation again?

Comment: Can't remember if there's an option to switch autosave on and off, but have a look, it could have been switched off accidentally. Have any other games experienced the same thing?

Comment: @Alex No, never had any save-game corruption like this before.

Comment: Didn’t Assassins Creed 2 have the Ubisoft always-online DRM? And when you’re not online, you can not save? Maybe that’s your issue?

Comment: @Kissaki Could be that I had some disconnection but for sure, in hour and more of gameplay, synchronization should have been happened more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing what caused your (new-) save-game loss the only thing you can do is backing up.

You have several options:

- Backup manually, copying your save-game files to a save place
- Backup via script, write a file-copying script

  - Run it manually
  - Run it via Cron/Tasks
- Use a file backup/copy software

  - For manual run
  - Which runs in the background and does automatically
- Version your files in-place with a VCS, like Git, HG, Bzr etc. You won’t have duplicate files and confusion this way, just a repository-folder with the files history.

Alls this of course only works if your game actually saves after you played. If it does not even save that is your problem, and you can’t do anything about losing game-state until you solve that.

The savegame files should be in `C:\Program Files\Ubisoft\Ubisoft Game Launcher\storage` for x86 systems, and in `C:\Program Files(x86)\Ubisoft\Ubisoft Game Launcher\storage` for x64 systems.

According to [a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iacUyZMNP84), that folder also includes a temp folder, which includes a save for each checkpoint. That way, you can rename your recent temp checkpoint file to a savegame, put it in your savegame folder, and then load it.

Comment: Good hints, but I was not able to find save-games files about Assassin's Creed II on my PC. Could it be that they are only saved online?

Comment: With ubisofts always-online DRM, yes, that could be. Then you would have no chance, no control over it.

Comment: Edited for info on folder and temp-saves

Comment: It seems promising but there isn't any folder /storage/ into C:/Program Files(x86)/ Ubisoft/ Ubisoft Game Launcher on my installation

Comment: … any other appropriate subfolders or -files? Sorry, more than that I can not help you. Those paths were mentioned at several places on the net though.